# Symfony 3 - Pass Object to EntityType

Tags: php, symfony

I try to post a `Guide` in my database. My request looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "comany": 1
}
```

My form:

```
$builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('company', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle:Company', 'allow_extra_fields' => true));
```

This is working, but it in my frontend it would be easier to make a request with the `company` as an object and not only passing the id. If I make a request like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "company": {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "company1"
   }
}
```

I get the error `Bad Request {"form":{"children":{"name":{},"company":{"errors":["This value is not valid."]}}},"errors":["This value is not valid."]}`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to pass the entire company object in the request, then you need to work on transforming the request data into something understandable by your form.

I would look into [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-submit-event), specifically the `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event. According to the documentation, hooking up to this event will allow you to:

> - Change data from the request, before submitting the data to the form
> - Add or remove form fields, before submitting the data to the form.